# Is there a way to pass a class as an argument in a function without it running the entire class?

Tags: python, class, methods, pygame

I am using Pygame to try to pass a class as an argument in a function so I can call the method, not the entire class. Every time I pass the class argument, it seems to run the class and since it is in a loop, that grinds it down pretty quickly. Can anyone help do that? Also is my code structured ok? I am trying to delete raindrops from a group and then generate a new row, but for now, just trying to figure a way to delete the raindrops from the group. Thank you!!! BTW, a bit new to Python and coding in general (not counting HTML5 and CSS3).

I have tried set the class as a variable (drop = Droplet()) and then try to run the function to delete. I have also tried to set the function inside the class as a method, and that failed too. I really appreciate any help. Thank you! I have done exhaustive research on Stack Overflow and on Google. I have tried .kill and .remove.

```
class Droplet(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Droplet, self).__init__(rainfall)
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/Glossy_Raindrop.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blitme(self.image, self.rect)


def dropground(Droplet):
    drop = Droplet()
    screenie = screen.get_rect()
    if not screen.get_rect().contains(drop.rect):
        print("delete")
        drop.kill()


def update_screen(rainfall):
    screen.fill((135, 206, 235))
    print(len(rainfall))
    rain_y_move(Droplet, rainfall)
    dropground(Droplet)
    rainfall.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Ultimately I just got a ton of raindrops being generated at once, which slows it down. I would like it to delete the raindrop in the group and then go from there and generate a new row. Like raining on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to create a `Droplet` object and to pass the object to the functions.

But, I recommend to use a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite).

Add an `.update` method the the `Droplet` class, which das the y-movement and the "kills" the drop if has fallen on the ground. All the parameters which are passed to the `.update` method of the `Group` are delegated to the `.updtate` method of the contained elements:

```py
class Droplet(Sprite):

   # [...]

   def update(self)

       self.rect = self.rect.move(0, speed)           

       screenie = screen.get_rect()
       if not screen.get_rect().contains(self.rect):
           print("delete")
           self.kill()
```

Create the group and append the drops:

e.g.

```py
rainfall = pygame.sprite.Group()
my_drop = Droplet()
rainfall.add(my_drop)
```

`Droplet.blitme` can be removed, because `pygame.sprite.Group` provides a [`.draw`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) method, which "blit" each surface of the group - for this the `.rect` and `.image` attribute of the [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) has to be set.

```py
def update_screen(rainfall):
    screen.fill((135, 206, 235))
    print(len(rainfall))

    rainfall.update();
    rainfall.draw(screen)        

    pygame.display.flip()

while run:

    update_screen(rainfall)
```

Comment: Do I make drop  = Droplet() as a global variable?

Comment: How come if not screen.get_rect().contains(drop.rect): does not become true after a raindrop leaves the screen and presumably rect?

Comment: Thank you Rabbid76! You are awesome! I upvoted your answer, but I am too new to mean anything around here. But you have my gratitude!